# Lightning - no today option on calendar popups

Tags: lightning

does anyone know if it's possible to get the "today" link at the bottom of calendar popups in lightning?

[image: Date box from lightning with no today link]

[image: Date box from classic with today link]

Comment: Is this for the standard lightning UI?

Comment: Yep it's for the standard lightning UI